# why does numpy array behaves this way

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I was working on a mini project which I intended to use pure Python without any external library.
But at a certain point, I got a **TypeError** like this `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'`. It was as a result of trying to directly square up all elements in a list like this:

```
my_list = [0, 7, 2, 9] 
print(my_list ** 2)
```

. Although I have already created a function that could square up the list, but when I tried multiplying a numpy array like this:

```
import numpy as np
my_list = np.array([0, 7, 2, 9])
print(my_list ** 2)# prints array[0, 49, 4, 9]
```

My question is why does this happen? Or does numpy has a special property that enables it to behave like this?

Comment: You are dealing with two different data types: Numpy vs Python list. As the error states, the operator ** isn’t defined for Lists. You can write your own function that implements the operator for lists that provides the same results as Numpy. You will then have to work on vectorizing your function so that you get the same performance as Numpy.

Comment: `my_list *2` and `my_list+my_list` also have different meanings (cf to numbers and `ndarray`)

Comment: In Python, operators like `+`, `*` and `**` are implemented by methods attached to one or both of the arguments.   Numbers most of these, lists and strings only have a few (with different meanings than numbers).  Numeric dtype arrays also implement most of these operators.  Operators and methods are documented for each class.

Comment: @hpaulj Under what circumstances would `x*2` and `x+x` have different meanings? For all builtin numeric types as well as all sequence types these two versions are equivalent and I'd also expect them to be equivalent for `ndarray` objects.

Comment: For `x` being a list or string.  Same result, but different from numeric calculations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.ndarray` defines its own dunder methods for operators such as [`__pow__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__pow__). That's how it manages to handle those operations elementwise. With builtin lists you can use a list comprehension instead:

```
[x**2 for x in my_list]
```

You can also define your own classes that expose such custom behavior:

```
>>> class PowList(list):
...     def __pow__(self, other):
...         return [x**2 for x in self]
... 
>>> my_list = PowList([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> my_list ** 2
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```